# Spring Cloud Connector Plan Information

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-connectors

I am using Spring Cloud Connector to bind to databases. Is there any way to get the plan of the bound service? When I extend an `AbstractCloudConfig` and do

```
cloud().getSingletonServiceInfosByType(PostgresqlServiceInfo.class)...
```

I will have information on the url and how to connect to the postgres. PostgresqlServiceInfo and others do not carry along the plan data. How can I extend the service info, in order to read this information form `VCAP_SERVICES`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By design, the `ServiceInfo` classes in Spring Cloud Connectors carry just enough information to create the connection beans necessary for an app to consume the service resources. Connectors was designed to be platform-neutral, and fields like `plan`, `label`, and `tags` that are available on Cloud Foundry are not captured because they might not be available on other platforms (e.g. Heroku).

To add the `plan` information to a `ServiceInfo`, you'd need to write your own `ServiceInfo` class that includes a field for the value, then write a `CloudFoundryServiceInfoCreator` to populate the value from the `VCAP_SERVICES` data that the framework provides as a `Map`. See the [project documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-connectors/spring-cloud-connectors.html#_adding_service_support) for more information on creating such an extension.

Another (likely easier) option is to use the newer `java-cfenv` project instead of Spring Cloud Connectors. `java-cfenv` supports Cloud Foundry only, and gives access to the full set of information in `VCAP_SERVICES`. See the [project documentation](https://github.com/pivotal-cf/java-cfenv#basic-usage) for an example of how you can use this library.

Comment: Hi Scott, I thought about pretty much the same (for extending Cloud Connector). Problem is, that the creators are maintained in a list and the first that accepts the data (service info creator `accept` method) will be used. Not sure, if custom ones are prefered, or this can lead to a race condition?

Comment: The methods in the `Cloud` class like the one mentioned in your post will return a list of all `ServiceInfo`s that match the provided criteria (e.g. service name or `ServiceInfo` type). These methods should return both the built-in `PostgresqlServiceInfo` and any custom `ServiceInfo`s that also match via `accept`). If you want to use `connectionFactory` from `AbstractCloudConfig` to get a `DataSource` Bean, you'd also need to write a custom `ServiceConnectorCreator` that looks a lot like `PostgresqlDataSourceCreator` but uses your custom `ServiceInfo` type for selection.